# iOS app crashing when calling alert message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

i have different apps where I use an alert message, so far never an issue.
Now I get this error. I usually call the alertview from the didbecomeactive method.
Can someone help me with this issue. Just getting started coding, so keep it slow :)
Many thanks

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSetM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa9737c0'
```

Comment: Post your code may be?

Comment: Your code has the issue man, show it to the world..

Comment: Here is some code for a working UIAlertView using ARC:     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Some Title" message:@"Some Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show]; If you are not using ARC (which you most likely should) you release the alert after show.

Comment: @Filip - Good job, but I believe he is trying to pass something into the message and he is trying to customize it but that value apparently is nil and leading to a crash. So, let's see his code first.. :)

Comment: Your calling `length` on `NSSet` somewhere. You could have set something to `id` than assigned a value of `NSSet` to it, and `NSSet` doesn't have a value of `length`

Answer (score -1):

One of the object your calculating length is converting to `NSSetM` object. Check the object which you are calculating `length` property of it, which is releases that object.Please use retain of it. or properly release the object after using it.

Comment: You have not posted any of code here and provided crash, as per crash we provided our idea. Just check with this, is it working or not and if possible post your code here to verify the issue.